# How to stop currently playing audio automatically when another play button in different UITableView cells are pressed? - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am a swift beginner currently working on my first iOS app.

I have a TableViewController which has several cells and each cell contains a play button. When a few play buttons are pressed, a few different audios are played at the same time, but I would like to stop a currently playing audio when another playing play button is pressed.

Here are the sample codes I created.

Please give me an advice. Thank you so much!

Comment: Please don’t throw all your code at us like spaghetti against the wall. Consider the “minimal” in [mcve].

Comment: You need to maintain model for this. Eg: When you play any music that cell model can be set to true. and on that moment you should set all cell model to false. And reload cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that every single cell has its own independent player. You want just *one* player, so that you can stop it and start a new sound. For example, make the one player a property of the view controller. Every cell can see it but there is just one.

Answer (score 1):

create an extension for `AVPlayer` because `AVPlayer` does not own condition for playing. extension given below.

```
extension AVPlayer {
    var isPlaying: Bool {
        return rate != 0 && error == nil
    }
}
```

use it while tap on play like this.

```
if player?.isPlaying == true {
   player?.pause()
   player?.seek(to: CMTime(seconds: 0, preferredTimescale: 60))
}
//set up you audio file to player
player?.play()
```